# Is it possible to install malicious code with a SQL injection attack

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-injection

We recently identified a security floor in some old code which was vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

The server is MS SQL Server 2012 running on Windows 2012.

During the investigation I have been asked if any malicious code has been installed via the vulnerability. The SQL server is once removed from the Webserver but does have access to the internet for Operating system Updates.

I was not aware and haven't heard of code being installed / downloaded via SQL injection and my immediate response would be no this isn't possible. However I thought I would ask the good people on Stack Overflow as there is always the possibility I'm wrong :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046

Comment: The answer is "Yes", @SLaks gave one way it can be done though it depends on what access your user has. Of course, you wouldn't be silly enough to be connecting with `sa` or an account that has been given server admin priviledges...

Comment: That depends on the privileges of the database user the application is connecting with and the privileges of the OS user the SQL Server is running with.

Comment: Ok thats very useful thanks. And thanks to whoever downvoted my question.

Comment: @MattWallis I UPVOTED you to encourage you. The anonymous downvoting is a plague at StackExchange. It reminds me of medieval ages.

Comment: I flagged your question as off topic (considered helpful) because it has nothing to do with programming. In my opinion there is a better site to ask this question: [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQL server can execute master..xp_cmdshell command which executes windows command line operations, allowing further taking over the server and installing things on it.
SQL Server also supports C# code embedding. I would take the server for forensics analysis if its important, or delete it altogether if it's not.

Comment: Thank you - I have tried executing the xp_cmdshell with the user account being used to access the server and it does not allow it. Is it the case that sa is required?

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default, and you need `sp_configure` to enable it. for `sp_configure`, you need the `ALTER SETTINGS` privilege, which by default only have the **sysadmin** and **serveradmin** roles on server (not database!) level.

Comment: Ok - thanks - so tentatively this is good news as its not possible that the xp_cmdshell was run.

Comment: You can't count on the fact that xp_cmdshell not being enabled, that no body managed to execute commands on your servers. There are many exploits out there, I would analyze the server or delete it and reinstall it if I were you.